Variance of a sample
Let the given data be $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$. Define the following:
$$y_1 = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{\sqrt{2}}, y_2 = \frac{x_1 + x_2 - 2x_3}{\sqrt{6}}, ..., y_{n-1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i - (n-1)x_n}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}$$
Show that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} y_i^2$$
where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of the $x_i$.
I tried to take a linear algebra approach and showed that the transformation from X to Y is an orthonormal transformation which preserve the distance and later use this fact. But I can't proceed further. I would appreciate to get some help in this!

There is no orthogonal map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^{n-1},.$ Rather than trying that  would try induction but beware that $\overline{x}$ also depends on $n,.$

Hint: $\sum (x_i-\overline x)^2=\sum x_i^2 -n\overline x^2$
